# How to show that this solution is a minimum.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am reading this paper from Peter Hess: On multiple positive solutions of nonlinear elliptic eigenvalue problems. Comm. Partial Differential Equations 6 (1981), no. 8, 951–961.

In the last page (part (vii)), he finds sub and super solutions to problem $2_k$, and then he uses a theorem that guarantee the existence of a solution $\hat{u}_k$ to problem $2_k$. From here, he implicity assumes that this solution is a minimal of the functional $$\frac{1}{2}\|u\|_H^2-\lambda\int_\Omega F_k(u)$$

Im saying that he assume this, because he uses the step (v) and (vi). Well, I know that this soluiton is a critical point of this functional, but how to show that this solution is a minimum point? I am also assuming that he is using a theorem of sub and super solutions like [this](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=WFwQ6a6fTIoC&pg=PA151&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see theorem 11.1)

If you need the paper, please send me an e-mail.

Comment: Technical note: other users do not see the email address in your profile. It is visible only to you and moderators.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, I fixed it. Anyway, the $5$ in your name, how can I type it?

Comment: By pressing the key just to the right of 4, and to the left of 6.

Comment: hahaha, am I get crazy, or the $5$ and the $PM$ are in diferrent levels?

Comment: Yes, this is how numbers appear in Georgia, which is the font used here: 1234567890ABC.